# Jenkins Email-ext not evaluating body groovy script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext, jenkins-email-ext

My email stage was working fine until recently and I am not sure what went wrong. For some reason, the body of email-ext is not being evaluated anymore. Here is the script I've been using on a declarative pipeline:

```
emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="my-email.template"}''',
         subject: "${EMAIL_SUBJECT}",
         to: test@test.com
```

Email is still being sent but content I receive looks like this now:

```
${SCRIPT, template="my-email.template"}
```

Email successfully sent but body not showing template:

[image]

I have tried using one single quote but it still is not being evaluated:

```
'${SCRIPT, template="my-email.template"}'
```

My plugin versions are:

- Email Extension: v2.79
- Email Extension Template Plugin: v1.2

There are no errors in the log so I am at a lost. Does anyone have any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Did you try using double quotes? I.e., `"""${SCRIPT, template="my-email.template"}"""`.

Comment: Hi @ShaneBishop, I tried triple double quotes and unfortunately issue still remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating the Email Extension plugin to version 2.81.